# Unable to expand conversation in Botium report

Tags: chatbot

In botium test report using `mocha - reporter mochawesome` we get Utterances wise result

ex -

> Welcome/Welcome_input-L1
>
> Welcome/Welcome_input-L2

Can we get actual conversation dialog in report. I have tried

```
"expandConvos": true,
"expandUtterancesToConvos": true
```

but i think it is not for reporting purpose. Can we expand conversation in report with request and response ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Botium CLI is using Mocha internally as a test runner. It supports all types of report formats supported by Mocha: https://mochajs.org/#reporters

Additionally, there is the mochawesome reporter included as well as a CSV exporter. Configuration is done with a positional parameter:

```
botium-cli run csv
```

*Some reporters accept additional options, those can be specified with the --reporter-options switch*

The rendering of the test output is up to the selected reporter - mochawesome is not in any way special to chatbot testing, so it doesn't support rendering of the conversation. If you want this kind of rendering, you will either have to code yourself (and make a pull request to the Github project), or use [Botium Box](https://botium.at)